# i need to write a function that subtract a monthly number from a number.

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to calculate the new balance of a credit card for every month i need to subtract the monthly payment from the balance to return a new balance but don't know how to make it keep subtracting until the cards balance is zero please help!

thank you in advance

```
var monthly = calculateMinimumPayment(1500);
var bal = 1500;
var i = 0;
while (bal > i) {
     bal - monthly;
}
console.log(bal);

function calculateMinimumPayment(a) {
var payment = ((a * .18) / 12) + (a * .02);
return payment;
}
```

Comment: you need to assign the result of the subtraction back to `bal`:  `bal = bal - monthly;`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you  want the program to do? Maybe add some sample input output

Comment: the function takes calculates the monthly payment i need to be able to subtract the monthly payment from the total balance which is 1500 and the recalculate the new monthly payment and a new total balance until the card is paid off

Comment: If every month you only paid the minimum, and the minimum is recalculated each month, in a 100 years time, you would still owe 0.14.  And this is without interest.. :)

Comment: Is school finishing up a semester or something?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I'm not sure if this is what you want though, if it isn't please comment below:

```
var monthly = calculateMinimumPayment(1500);
var bal = 1500;
var i = 0;
while (bal > i) {
    bal -= monthly;
}  
console.log(bal);

function calculateMinimumPayment(a) {
     var payment = ((a * .18) / 12) + (a * .02);
     return payment;
}
```

Comment: don't know if you saw this up there but just incase i resent it here.the function takes calculates the monthly payment i need to be able to subtract the monthly payment from the total balance which is 1500 and the recalculate the new monthly payment and a new total balance until the card is paid off

Answer (score 1):

You need to update value of `bal` in the while loop by doing `bal = bal - monthly`.

If you want the value of `bal` to be non-negative, you will need to add one more condition in the while loop condition, just do `(bal - monthly) >= 0`.

```js
var monthly = calculateMinimumPayment(1500);
var bal = 1500;
var i = 0;

while (bal - monthly >= 0) {
  bal = bal - monthly;
}

console.log(bal);

function calculateMinimumPayment(a) {
  var payment = ((a * .18) / 12) + (a * .02);
  return payment;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't '(bal - monthly) >= 0' be sufficient? You can assume that if bal is less than zero, a negative number minus anything (monthly should not be negative) will be below 0.